# Please create the 1001-spikes tag so I can post a question!

Tags: support, tags

Please create the `1001-spikes` tag so I can post a question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't create a tag without a question. Just ask your question and use the platform tag(for example pc) and add a note at the bottom if your question requesting the tag, someone will then make the tag for you and remote said note.

Comment: If this post contains weird errors, I blame mobile and autocorrect.

Comment: Here's the question, if you have a moment to edit it and create the tag: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170845/what-are-the- consequences-of-skipping-a-level